# Tableview reloadData not working with tableView displaying array of NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults, reloaddata

I have a `tableView` that displays an `array` of stored `NSUserDefaults`. On trying to delete one of the rows, I am able to update the array of my stored defaults but this does not get reflected in the tableView.

In short the `tableview.reloadData` for some reason doesn't reload my `tableView`.

Below is my code for calling the `usedefaults` in `UIViewController`

```
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    encodedData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "newSave") as? NSData
    saveArticlesArray = (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: encodedData! as Data) as? [SaveArticle])!
    offTableView.reloadData()
}

//populating the table

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OfflineCell", for: indexPath) as! OfflineTableViewCell
   cell.offTitle.text = saveArticlesArray[indexPath.row].saveTitle
    return cell
}

//Deleting a row and its related stored userdefault

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete{
         var tempArray: [AnyObject] = saveArticlesArray as [AnyObject]
        tempArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            print("reached dispacth")
            //self.offTableView.reloadData()
            tableView.reloadData()
        }

        encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: tempArray) as NSData
        UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "newSave")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }    
}
```

Please note that the value of the selected row does get deleted when I close and reopen the `ViewController`. All I need is to reload the `tableView` so that the user can see that the row has got deleted.

Comment: After removing data from `tempArray` you are not updating `saveArticlesArray`

Comment: Yes but how do I do that in `editingStyle` func as `saveArtilcesArray` is `unarchieved` from stored `UserDefaults` in `viewDidAppear` above

Comment: Unrelated but remove all `as Data` and `as NSData` bridge casts and there is a dedicated method `data(forKey:)` in `UserDefaults`

Comment: @vadian Thanks for the tip! Still a novice at swift :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your method `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` with this one hope this will solve your problem.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete{
        saveArticlesArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            print("reached dispacth")
            //self.offTableView.reloadData()
            tableView.reloadData()
        }

        encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: saveArticlesArray) as NSData
        UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "newSave")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
}
```